# how to put array values in TS to NgFor HTML

Tags: angular

I have select :

```html
<select (change)="getYear(year)">
  <option value="year" *ngFor="let var of array; let i = index"
    {{year.year}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

how can i setup the typescript so than i can put the values of array in to option ?

Comment: Please show the array

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is incorrect. Try like this:

Assuming this is array of objects where 'year' is a property

```
<select (change)="getYear($event.target.value)">
   <option [ngValue]="var.year" *ngFor= let var of array; let i = index">{{var.year}} 
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is my ts: 
getYear(year: string){
let d = new Date();
let y = d.getFullYear();
this.array.push(y)
}

is that ok ?

Comment: i want 2019 become "var.year"

Comment: Please do this for test above the select and show me the result {{array | json}}

Comment: unexpected token T_T

Comment: Then console.log(array) in TS. I need to see what's in there